# How can I make a 50" long PDF from an email with preserving links?

Tags: email, pdf, links

Windows 10 on Lenovo YOGA, using Thunderbird and Wondershare's PDFElement. Email is a newsletter (in HTML I'm pretty sure); when I make a PDF it breaks into many ugly 8.5" x 11" pgs. but all the links are active. I can make it 1 pg by using the printer's page set up to extend the height to 50" but then all the links are dead.

My ideal is to create an archive of 3 years of newsletters as a single page PDF with all links active. Can any one help?

Comment: Thanks, KJ. Giving it a shot!